# How to deactivate a specific tab button on a specific tab screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I have an application with 3 tab buttons as below. On the ScreenA screen in the FirstTab, you can switch to the ScreenB screen with a button. I blocked going back to ScreenA from ScreenB. But if we press FirstTab while ScreenB is open, ScreenA screen opens. When the ScreenB screen is open, I want the FirstTab button to be deactivated in the tabbar at the bottom. How do I do this?

```js
function FirstTab() {
    return (
        <MainStack.Navigator>
            <MainStack.Screen name={"ScreenA"} component={ScreenA} />
            <MainStack.Screen name={"ScreenB"} component={ScreenB} />
        </MainStack.Navigator>
    )
}

function SecondTab() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>SecondTab Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

function ThirdTab() {
    return (
        <View >
            <Text>ThirdTab Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

function TabScreens() {
    (<Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: () => {
                let icon;
                if (route.name === 'FirstTab') {
                    icon = <View style={{ height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
                } else if (route.name === 'SecondTab') {
                    icon = <View style={{ height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "blue" }} />
                } else if (route.name === 'ThirdTab') {
                    icon = <View style={{ height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "yellow" }} />
                }
                return icon
            },
        })}
    >
        <Tab.Screen name={"FirstTab"} component={FirstTab} />
        <Tab.Screen name={"SecondTab"} component={SecondTab} />
        <Tab.Screen name={"ThirdTab"} component={ThirdTab} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}


export default function App() {
    return (
        <MainStack.Navigator>
            <MainStack.Screen name={"Splash"} component={Splash} />
            <MainStack.Screen name="TabScreens" component={TabScreens} />
        </MainStack.Navigator>
    );
}
```